# Live usb 14.0.4 upgrade for more driver

Tags: 14.04, live-usb

I have problem with live USB Ubuntu - it doesn`t see my network card.

My question is how can I install more drivers to the live Ubuntu on USB, and where do I configure this?

My network card is atheros ar8161